# GNU Octave use as CLI and get output in STDIO or write to file

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, octave, gnu

I would like to call GNU Octave from my script with input data and get plot points back from GNU Octave to plot them with other tool.

Is it possible to use GNU Octave as CLI command under Linux Debian and feed it with input data from text file and get as output draw points written to file or as output in STDIO?

It seems to me it is only possible to use GNU Octave from its GUI but I'm not interested in GUI mode but using it as Linux CLI command to generate the output to file from input that would be in file or just STDIO input.

I also saw somewhere that you may kind of log into GNU Octave terminal and issue commands but this is not suitable for me because I cannot run in an interactive mode. I'm looking for a batch mode - something like:

```
octave input.txt output.txt
```

Is it possible to use GNU Octave this way? I would appreciate if you could give any basic snippet to begin work with it.

Comment: https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Invoking-Octave-from-the-Command-Line.html

Comment: The batch-file tag is not relevant for this problem.  You're in Linux, which shell are you running?

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm using classic sh or bash. I think I found a lead in [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/B-sbaSTDpYg?t=216) and found `--eval CODE` and `--no-gui` flag in GNU Octave, version 4.4.1 for Debian. Maybe by using  `--eval` for passing code and stream redirection for file content I could run calculation in CLI without a need to provide any file but just a text content of the code to evaluate and a string of input points? I guess I don't need in the calc script any output to the file because I could just print the result and capture it from CLI's STDIO right?